# random variable probability(binary tree)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I have this problem on random variables and a binary tree. The problem goes like this: The experiment is creating a binary tree with 4 nodes. The random variable X is the number of leaves.

My first question is what can my possible values be for the random variable X? Would it be 1 and 2 since we can't have rooted binary tree that has 4 nodes with 0 leaves? My second question is how would i find the probability of X=1 and X=2? I started with X=1 and drew each possible trees, this seemed like a similar problem where i tossed a coin 4 times and determined the # of heads. But then i realized that this would not work because as X increases we would get a node with 2 leaves. So its not just a matter of left child is 1/2 right child is 1/2 probability. Would we have a 1/3 chance of a getting a left node, 1/3 chance of getting a right node, 1/3 chance of getting both a left and right node since we have 3 possibilities? Since the root is always going to be the same we would have something like 1*1/3*1/3*1/3 which is 1/27. Since there are 8 possible binary trees with 4 nodes and 1 leaf, would P(X=1) = (1/27)^8?

Comment: Neat problem.  Have you studied conditional probabilities yet?  You want to use the "binomial approach" and condition on the fact that there are four total nodes (and therefore, impossible configurations)